# Topology: Homeomorphism from R^2 to itself preserving standard topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, continuous-homomorphisms

I need to prove that there exists a homeomorphism f from R2 to itself with its standard topology such that:

when considering any pair of three distinct points (x1, x2, x3) and (y1, y2, y3),  f maps
(x1, x2, x3) -> (y1, y2, y3)

So far, I've shown that there exists a homeomorphism from the topological space with set X= {x1,x2,x3} and standard topology to Y={y1,y2,y3} with the same topology.

In order to extend this to R2, I'm considering the function

g = { f if x in X

```
  { Id if x in R\X
```

Is it correct to assume that, since f is on an open, it can be defined in a way that there is no point of discontinuity when g runs from R\X to X?

If not, how can I define a homeomorphism that satisfies the conditions in the problem?

Comment: You can use Mobius transformations, specifically with [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Cross-ratio_preservation). The points are written as complex numbers. Take $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to be $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $w_1,w_2,w_3$ to be $y_1,y_2,y_3$. Then the map is the function that takes $z$ to $w$.

Comment: Your $g$ is not going to even be injective in some cases. Suppose $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=3,y_1=2,y_2=3,y_3=4$. Then $g$ is sending $4\notin X$ to $4$ and $x_3=3\in X$ to $4$.

Comment: Your title says "homeomophism", but your question says "homomorphism". These are not the same thing. Which one do you mean? conditionalMethod's suggestion will give you a homeomophism, but not a homomorphism.

Comment: I meant homeomorphism throughout, sorry for the confusion

Comment: [A general case of $n$ points in $\Bbb R^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543076/interpolation-using-homeomorphism).