# Is there a homeomorphism in a rectangle that keep fixed the boundary and send one given point to another?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524765/topological-homeomorphism-which-takes-convergent-sequence-to-a-specific-converge/4525437?noredirect=1#comment9508668_4525437) was used a lemma that says that given a rectangle $R=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ and $x,y\in int(R)$ then there is a homeomorphism $\phi:R\to R$ keeping the boundary of $R$ fixed such that $\phi(x)=y$. So anyone has a reference for that lemma? (Or a solution). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $ABCD$ is a rectangle and $X,Y$ are in the interior.

To start, map $\triangle ABX$ to $\triangle ABY$. For example, use [barycentric coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system): the point in $\triangle ABX$ with coordinates $(u,v,w)$ with $u,v,w\ge 0, u+v+w=1$ maps into the point in $\triangle ABY$ with the same coordinates $(u,v,w)$.

Do the same with the other three pairs of triangles: $\triangle BCX/\triangle BCY, \triangle CDX/\triangle CDY, \triangle DAX/\triangle DAY$. If barycentric coordinates were used, those maps will match on the edges $AX,BX,CX,DX$ and will all together define the desired (continuous) map.

This map has a continuous inverse: namely the result of the same construction, but swapping the roles of points $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Very nice proof! (+1)

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that for each plane triangle $\Delta(U,V,W)$ with vertices $U,V,W$ the "standard $2$-simplex" $\Delta^2$ = convex hull of the three unit vectors $e_i$ in $\mathbb R^3$ =  $\{(t_1,t_2,t_3) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid t_i \ge 0, t_1+t_2+t_3 = 1\}$ is mapped via $(t_1,t_2,t_3) \mapsto t_1U+t_2V+t_3W$ homeomorphically onto $\Delta(U,V,W)$.

Comment: @KritikerderElche I wasn't sure how much to expand on the proof without obscuring the main idea ("cannot see the forest for the trees" problem). I've added a link to "barycentric coordinates" on Wikipedia, for the curious. Otherwise, I have also skipped: proof that those maps are all continuous, proof that they are nicely glued together, proof that this map has an inverse. (Hope if OP need clarification they will leave a comment.)

Comment: This also follows more generally directly from the fact that [$\mathbb{R^n}$ is strongly locally homogeneous space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938735/mathbbrn-is-a-strongly-locally-homogeneous-space), since in an SLH space each open, connected set has this property (e.g. Corollary 1 [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.433.3333&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).